# How to specify an array of integers as compiler commandline define -D

Tags: c++11

I would like to be able to specify at compile time a list of integers
These integers are used to output debug information on certain components in my system which have those intgers as id. The actual implementatio of printing that debug information is in one of our own libraries, but I need to be able to specify which ids I want to debug from the project that is using that library, with something like

`-DDEBUG_SENSORIDS="12,23,45"`

In the actual C++ code the define (when present of course) needs to be converted to an array or vector of integers.

The following solution results in a compile error

`int debugIds[] = { DEBUG_SENSORIDS };`

```
<command-line>:0:31: error: expected '}' before ';' token
src\SenseNode.cpp:19:20: note: in expansion of macro 'DEBUG_SENSORIDS'
int debugIds[] = { DEBUG_SENSORIDS };
                   ^ 
src\SenseNode.cpp:19:36: error: expected declaration before '}' token
  int debugIds[] = { DEBUG_SENSORIDS };
                                     ^
```

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes:

```
-DDEBUG_SENSOR_VALUES=12,23,45
```

Comment: @Bascy - other two points: be sure to use the correct identifier (`DEBUG_SENSOR_VALUES` or `DEBUG_SENSORIDS`?) and the correct syntax for integer arrays (not `int[] ids =  { <some values> };` but `int ids[] = { <some values> };`)

Comment: @max66 I should have copy/pasted the code, but in stead i retyped it, and made these dumb mistakes, sorry! ... So the code is actually like you proposed. I editted the orignla question accordingly

Comment: The quotes will likely be removed by the command interpreter (the backslashes hint at `cmd`, not `bash`, but it should be similar with both of them). The only difference is probably that the string can contain spaces with quotes.

Comment: @Bascy Typing does not seem to be your forte ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, it was a stupid mistake where the -D declaration had an ; attached to the end